# Customize "Your Most Popular Sites" in IE?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

In IE9 the default New Tab behavior is to show a grid of what it thinks are the sites you most often visit ("Your Most Popular Sites"). Pretty accurate, but I'd like to customize this page. Maybe pin some sites at the top. Also, it'd be nice to have a larger grid with more sites listed.

[image]

So, pinning sites is probably a feature request, but maybe there's a way (resource-based RSS feed, ActiveX control, whatever) to build a similar page that includes the list from "Your Most Popular Sites" ...?

Expanding the grid sounds like a setting or registry entry...?

Any other customization folks have done to this page?

Comment: I don't think you can, but I would love that too.

Comment: Visit the pages you want to add, then hit refresh x 1000 ;)

Comment: @vemv - Not exactly what i had in mind, but sounds like a decent fallback plan. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it looks like you can, in fact, add rows to "Your Most Popular Sites" with a registry value.

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TabbedBrowsing\NewTabPage\NumRows`

It's a `DWORD.` In RegEdit, i added `NumRows` to the `NewTabPage` key and set it to 3. I tried 5 but that's a bit much. Incidentally, `NumCols` and `NumColumns` does not seem to work. (Disclaimer: it's the registry, so be careful. Backups. Etc etc etc.)

I'd still like to get more columns and be able to otherwise customize this page as described in the question.

[image]